# RPC on etherjs is not connected only on iOS

Tags: react-native, ethers.js

Apps built with ethers in React Native do not work only on iOS

```
export const getEtherBalance = async (walletAddr: string) => {
  const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(sepoliaRpc);
  try {
    const balance = await provider.getBalance(walletAddr)
    const result = ethers.utils.formatEther(balance)
    return roundingOff(result)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    return "0"
  }
}
```

Sepolia RPC is on infura and works normally on Android.

```
[Error: could not detect network (event="noNetwork", code=NETWORK_ERROR, version=providers/5.7.0)]
```

I opened the ATS related settings in info.plist and made a request to axios for network testing, but communication through axios was successful.